# An internal error was found with this API project

Tags: google-maps

When I run https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=chinese+restaurants+in+sheffield&sensor=false&key=xxx (my API key substituted here I get)

{
   "error_message" : "An internal error was found for this API project.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

As it is only me using this, and I am not going over 50 requests a minute, I am rather baffled as to why it's doing this.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: I do have the same problem. Have you found any resolution to date?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot I had asked the question, I will put an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=chinese+restaurants+in+sheffield&key=XXX did the trick for me, i.e. you no longer need the &sensor=false bit.